# problems with video playback speed and sound in 14.04?

Tags: nvidia, sound, video, 14.04, smplayer

my machine is having problems with video playback with both SmPlayer and the built in player. the videos are sped up and sound is chopped. i didn't change any settings or mess with them in any way since my upgrade or before. anyone else have this problem?   all my reading leads me to believe it is an issue with the Nvidia driver, but am still unsure. if so should i wait for an update or do it myself?

i have NVIDIA® Quadro® NVS 160M5 256MB DDR25 running on a Dell latitude e6400.

Comment: You can try installing the proprietary Nvidia drivers if you haven't yet.

Comment: Having a rather similar problem myself, on a completely different set up

Answer (score 1):

i too had the same problem and i got rid of it in this way just type this command in terminal 
you can open your terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl+alt+t</kbd>

and then just type the terminal or copy paste it

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```